# Is it possible to determine what caused a duplicate key values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a job who makes replication between two databases and after I insert new value in  first table `tbl_company_market_service_phone_number` I get this error from the job ,and the value not exists in table wich is replicated data (second table).

```
Error:Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'tbl_company_market_service_phone_number' with    
unique index 'IX_tbl_company_market_service_phone_number_fld_uk'. The duplicate key value is   
(65b763ac-6f8f-4fe6-b76c-02a75b71dbe1).
```

How can I find what key value is `(65b763ac-6f8f-4fe6-b76c-02a75b71dbe1)` ? Or find out the cause of job faill.

Comment: if you insert one and it says duplicated key...than the one you just inserted is the value isn't it......

Comment: Yes I know but what is the cause if in second table don't exists the value

Comment: can you be clear of what you want??? you want to not insert into any table if it is duplicate value in one of the table? if so use something like start transaction, if it fails then don't commit

Comment: If you are getting this error, then the duplicate key must have existed in the target table when the insert was being performed.  Something else, like a rollback or other error handling, may have removed it be the time you went to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is not in the replicated data

Did you check the source table

It is telling you table name tbl_company_market_service_phone_number
And that is the name of stated name of the source table

Comment: thanks,the row exists in the replicated data, I found it but with different name